# Yii2 FileHelper::findFiles() does not work with an option

Tags: yii2

When I simply use

```
FileHelper::findFiles(realpath($config['sourcePath']));
```

It works.But when I try to pass some options to it,it does not work.Unfortunately,It does not give any error.

```
FileHelper::findFiles(realpath($config['sourcePath']),['only'=>['*.php']]);
```

Any idea why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax should be `.php` and not `*.php`. It isn't very clear in the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper.html#findFiles%28%29-detail) though. Here is the explanation for the trailing `/`:

> For example, '/a/b' matches all file paths ending with '/a/b'; and '.svn/' matches directory paths ending with '.svn'

We can therefore deduce that `.svn` will match all files ending in `.svn`.

Comment: I tried .php as well.Still it gives me the error.When I execute this command through console ,it works fine but when I try to run it on browser ,it stops working.